# ajaxStart/ajaxStop for RequireJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, requirejs

In RequireJS, is there any functions equivalent to JQuery's ajaxStart and ajaxStop? Or how to monitor ***global*** ajax status while requirejs is loading any new javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing. Modules are not loaded using xhr. There are JavaScript files injected in the DOM and requireJS waits for script to load.

You can setup a callback that will be called when module loaded:

```
require(['yourmodule'], function (module) {
    alert('Module has loaded.');
}
```

Comment: I see. Is there a way to get notified before/after EVERY define/require? I tried hooking my callbacks by overriding window.require and window.define, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it work by overriding default require function.
I am using coffeescript, and the code follows:

```
_root = @
_require = @require
@requirehook = new class
  constructor: -> @count = 0
  require: =>
    @onAjaxStart?() if not @count
    @count += 1
    _require.apply _root, arguments
    @count -= 1
    @onAjaxStop?() if not @count
  ajaxStart: (fn) => @onAjaxStart = fn
  ajaxStop: (fn) => @onAjaxStop = fn

@require = @requirehook.require
```